# Conditional Filter in SSRS Dataset

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using the following expression but it fails when ExTyp="f" IFF condition is added. Not sure where I am doing it wrong:

```
" & IIF(Parameters!ExTyp.Value ="S", "AND ELG.MBR_EFCT_DT<= '"& Parameters!EndDate.Value &"' AND (ELG.MBR_TRM_DT>= '" & Parameters!StartDate.Value & "' OR ELG.MBR_TRM_DT IS NULL) ","") & "  
        " & IIF(Parameters!ExTyp.Value ="F", "AND (ELG.MBR_EFCT_DT>=G.GRP_ORIG_EFCT_DT AND ELG.MBR_EFCT_DT<=CURRENT DATE) AND (ELG.MBR_TRM_DT >ELG.MBR_EFCT_DT OR ELG.MBR_TRM_DT IS NULL)" ,"") & "
```

Comment: Can you describe your IIF in a sentence? For example, if ExType = "S" and date (MBR_EFCT_DT) is less than or greater than the parameter end date, then .... , if ExType = "F", then .... , etc.

Comment: IIF is case sensitive.  Are you inputting an 'f' and expecting to return the same results as if you input an "F"?

Comment: The IIF looks OK - other than the extra `& "` at the end that I assume is from a partial expression. Are you getting an error or just No Data? If an error, run it in Visual Studio and let us know what the error message says.

Comment: Is there any reason this can't go into the underlying query?

Comment: @HardCode - It looks like he's building the query based on the parameters in the dataset expression. I suppose he could just UNION them and use the @ExType in the WHERE clause (`WHERE @ExType = 'S' AND ...`) but this should work with less effort.